# Python simple http get server test

Tags: python, httpserver

What I do wrong on this code?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer

PORT_NUMBER = 3000

class serverHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('yo')
        return

try:
    #Create a web server and define the handler to manage the
    #incoming request
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), serverHandler)
    print 'Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER

    #Wait forever for incoming htto requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
    server.socket.close()
```

When I tested boom performance, the performance result is very bad...

When I firing the Boom from my server:

```
boom -n 100000 -c 10000 http://localhost:3000
```

I receive this result:

```
Summary:
  Total:    25.5676 secs
  Slowest:  4.2101 secs
  Fastest:  0.9872 secs
  Average:  1.7560 secs
  Requests/sec: 380.0513

Status code distribution:
  [200] 9717 responses

Response time histogram:
  0.987 [1] |
  1.309 [1792]  |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  1.632 [2670]  |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  1.954 [1681]  |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  2.276 [2616]  |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  2.599 [446]   |∎∎∎∎∎∎
  2.921 [283]   |∎∎∎∎
  3.243 [171]   |∎∎
  3.565 [31]    |
  3.888 [1] |
  4.210 [25]    |

Latency distribution:
  10% in 1.0313 secs
  25% in 1.5239 secs
  50% in 1.7353 secs
  75% in 2.0630 secs
  90% in 2.2717 secs
  95% in 2.6155 secs
  99% in 3.1570 secs
```

The same test with other languages have way better performance, see the source here: https://github.com/ericmdantas/bm

Comment: You are doing absolutely nothing wrong in the code.

Comment: well I'm not gonna go through all your repo for tests. First thing I can see is that you don't handle your connections at all. you should prolly change that, have a connection pool, etc.  But HOW exactly are you testing it? Number of concurrent connections . nr of requests per connection? what did you write your tests in. Could it be the test code?

Comment: Hello @ingrid.e, I using in my tests the Boom app (see this repo: https://github.com/rakyll/boom) using this command line: "boom -n 100000 -c 10000 http://localhost:3000" where 
  -n  Number of requests to run.
  -c  Number of requests to run concurrently. Total number of requests cannot
      be smaller than the concurency level.

Comment: then you need to handle your connections, have a connection pool, understand if your client is using keep alive or not, etc

Comment: Thanks, I'll try do this and do the retest de service.